# What does 讲好中国故事 really mean?

Tags: culture

Reading the Chinese language mainstream media,I often encounter the words 讲好中国故事but do not really understand what that means.

Since when news media has begun to tell stories,that is, something unreal or fictional? Do readers of news media like to read such stories?

Answer (score 2):

> 讲好中国故事
> tell well, the story of China

First of all, 故事 ("stories") aren't necessarily fictitious (perhaps you're thinking of a child asking their parent to 给我讲故事, and the parent telling, say, the story of the Three Little Pigs).  The word 故事 is used in 爱情故事 = "love story" or 背景故事 = "back story", which may be true.  Used in e.g., 编故事 = "to tell tales", it's likely fictitious.

In this case, 中国故事 could mean "the story of China" (referring to China's history) or "the stories of China" (referring to the experiences of Chinese people); it's likely both.

The 好 is acting as a complement for the verb 讲 = "to narrate", saying to do it well (thorough and complete).  This appears to be an abbreviated form of a 把 sentence (perhaps for a show's title, or for a snappy catchphrase), so you'll usually see e.g. 把衣服洗好 rather than 洗好衣服, or 他把作业做好了 rather than 他做好作业了.

Answer (score 2):

Personally, I think that people who write such long sentences should be shot!

Not familiar with 沙龙 as "meeting", thought 沙龙 was a place where you go to get your hair or your nails done!

公务员胜任特征首在务实于11月12日在国家行政学院港澳培训中心隆重举行。
The first practical meeting of the Civil Servants Competency Characteristics was held on November 12th at the National Administration Institute Hongkong-Macao training centre.

日本政府青年公务员代表团参加了本次沙龙。
A delegation of young civil servants from Japan took part in this get-together.

他们与国家行政学院的专家学者们就政府职能、公务员胜任力等话题进行了热烈交流。
They carried out lively exchanges with specialist scholars from the National Administration Institute regarding government roles and civil servants' competency.

国家行政学院国际部副主任周萍果主持了本次沙龙。
National Administration Institute International Department Deputy Director Zhou Pingguo took charge of this salon.

“讲好中国故事”主题沙龙是由国家行政学院国际部策划、主办和负责管理的一个集学术性、实践性、国际性于一体的交流平台，旨在贯彻落实党的十八届三中全会精神，坚定中国特色社会主义的道路自信、理论自信和制度自信，创新对外传播方式，探索对外话语体系，着力打造融通中外的中国表述，讲好中国故事，传播好中国声音。通过开启沙龙这样一个创新载体，集聚中外专家资源，研究如何阐释中国道路，探索涉外培训教学的新模式和新思路，增强涉外培训在中国话语国际传播中的交流平台和品牌效应。

The "Tell China's Story Well" themed meeting was planned, organised supervised and managed by the National Administration Institute International Department as an academic and practical international open exchange platform, which aims to implement the spirit of China's 18th National Congress, to strengthen confidence in Chinese-style socialism, theory and systems and how they are disseminated and presented internationally, to explore foreign discourse systems, to make an effort to develop and circulate the Chinese point of view, to "Tell China's Story Well", to properly disseminate China's voice abroad.

Basically, The Party wants to ensure that China's story and voice is not being misunderstood abroad.

Comment: The last sentence covers the whole thing.

Comment: Shot by gun or by camera? Does that mean that before the time when the current big boss is in power, the media all told lies or got misunderstood due to their bad narrative skills?

Comment: "Should be shot!" Just a joke! A common thing to say in English! “讲好中国故事” is in this case simply the Communist Party of China wishing to ensure that their message about China is being correctly disseminated at home and abroad. The West does its best to spread anti-china propaganda. The BBC is very good at spreading low-level anti-Chinese propaganda. They need an enemy to blame for their own failures.

Answer (score 2):

This is a common practice in external promotion, where the stories we often tell are generally fictional, detached from reality, unrealistic, and have an element of exaggeration. During Mao Zedong's era, the official media claimed that one mu of land could yield over 10,000 kilograms of grain, which can be seen as telling a good story about China. Similarly, on YouTube, Li Ziqi promotes how great rural life is, but it's not necessarily true. It's similar to the Cultural Revolution period when students(More accurately, students who are sent to rural areas for re-education were originally from the city, not the countryside. This is because only city residents are eligible for re-education, and if you were already a rural resident, you would not be considered "sent down.") who were sent down to the countryside mostly wanted to leave and return to the city as soon as possible.

Comment: I heard that it was high school students that were sent to countryside, not the college students as you said, because at that time there were not many students of university available in China.

Comment: In 1977, the college entrance exam in China resumed. This was the major reason how and why China economy boomed. Many people like to say democracy promotes economic development. But, China mainland has never been a democratic country. Why and how their economy developed ? They have high quality college graduates ! It has nothing to do with democracy or dictatorship.

Comment: Thanks for the information. So your story is more interesting and truthful than many official media. Please share more, if any.

Comment: Thanks, Whozcry. at the same time, I'd like @Nobody to know Chinese are the most hard                             working people in the world. Visit Vietnam, a very close neighbor of China, you will see the huge difference.

Comment: @NanningYouth I am Chinese myself. I know what you're talking about. I was only trying to explain how the poverty in China during 1949 -1979 happened.